# Probability of heads in a biased coin

Tags: probability

Given $N$ flips of the same coin resulting in $k$ occurrences of 'heads', what is the probability density function of heads-probability of the coin?

Comment: Is this homework? If so then please tag it as such.

Comment: Also please tell us your current thinking on this question, c.f.: http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: This is not homework.
I've found some approaches on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair).
The bayesian approach depends on an arbitrary prior distribution, which seems bizarre. He recommends using a distribution centered on 0.5 but uses an uniform. The choice of the prior distribution is not so important? How can I trust a distribution that was chosen arbitrarily?
I don't understand how the frequentist approach might give me a distribution. 
A friend said that bootstrapping might give a good answer, is it true? How would that work?

Comment: Reading about priors, the article on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) seems to recommend Jeffrey's prior (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior#Bernoulli_trial) which is 1/sqrt[p(1-p)], although I didnt understand the explanation of why.

Comment: The distribution function cannot be estimated from the coin results alone? It will always require a prior distribution? This is counterintuitive.

Comment: @LeoHMArruda Can you explain the context in which such a question arises (how did you arrive at this question?)

Comment: The question you have posed is not directly about the fairness of the coin.

Comment: Well it is basically the problem of finding out if a Bernoulli trial is biased and how much by repeating it many times. I was discussing it as a simplified model of hypothesis testing in a class.

Answer (score 1):

> Reading about priors, the article on wikipedia (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) seems to recommend Jeffreys' prior (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior#Bernoulli_trial) which is 1/sqrt[p(1-p)], although I didnt understand the explanation of why.

You're not clear as to whether you're confused with how they arrived at that particular prior, or the purpose of the Jeffreys prior.

The Wikipedia article has a pretty good summary of some of the advantages and disadvantages of Jeffreys priors. You can google around if you're still confused or just say so :) .

The way you find the Jeffreys prior is you need to first find the [Fisher information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) of the parameter. [Here](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/old03/5102/notes/fish.pdf) is a paper that derives the binomial Fisher information. After we do that, we take the square root of this, and then use this as the prior. The reason why '$ \propto $' is used is because when you're finding the posterior distribution, it's easier to find with up to proportion to the parameter and then solve for the normalizing constant for the posterior.

I have to go to class now, but I'll try to elaborate more later if no one else does.

Comment: Thanks R S, I'll take a look. Do you agree with the choice of the Jeffrey prior in this case?

Comment: To be honest I'm not certain. I just know the basics of Bayesian inference. While I've seen simulations that people run demonstrating the power of various priors versus frequentist methods, I've also had people tell me that non-informative are big no-noes and should be avoided.

Comment: A friend pointed out that in this wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Effect_of_different_prior_probability_choices_on_the_posterior_beta_distribution) there is a good discussion about the priors. Apparently, one should use Beta(0,0)=uniform when one does not know anything, Beta(1,1) when we know that both extremes of probability are possible and Beta(1/2,1/2)=Jeffrey's somewhere in the middle (? Maybe sth close to 1/2?). I have the impression that there is much more rhetorics than straightforward mathematics in this solution.

Comment: From my understanding, priors are most powerful when we have at least a little bit of prior information (even if it's very trivial). A clever problem (complete with simulation) can be found [here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2013/01/lions-tigers-and-bears.html). I also know that sometimes you have some basic information that you can take into account sometimes.

Comment: Here and elsewhere: Harold Jeffreys, so Jeffreys's (the form he preferred himself) or Jeffreys' for any possessive with explicit apostrophe.

Comment: @LeoHMArruda: Beta(1, 1) is uniform.  You shouldn't use Beta(0,0).  The Jeffreys' prior defined for when you don't know anything.

Answer (score 1):

Because the $N$ (independent) coin flips occur with probability proportional to $p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$, the likelihood induced on the coin's bias is $\textrm{Beta}(k + 1, N-k + 1)$.

You could have picked any parametrization of the bias.  You chose to represent it as a probability $0 \le p \le 1$, but it could have been an "odds" $0\le o$, or a log-odds $\ell$.  Since this choice is arbitrary, your prior should be independent of this choice. Jeffreys found the only prior that satisfies this "indifference" to the choice of parametrization: the Jeffreys prior, $\textrm{Beta}(\frac12, \frac12)$.

Pointwise product of densities gives the posterior $\textrm{Beta}(k+\frac12, N-k+\frac12)$.

Comment: Why Beta(1/2, 1/2)? This is a bimodal distribution with the weight concentrated around 0 and 1. OP, and future readers, will be interested in explanation about why this is the prior, rather than simply a prior among many alternatives. Some coins could be 1 with probability 0.75, so a prior of Beta(3,1) could represent that... or Beta(30,10)...

Comment: @user777: The distribution is over the coin's probability $p$ — it is not binomial, but Beta.  OP already said he was familiar with the Jeffreys' prior, but I'll mention it as you suggest.  I did say that "assuming you know nothing to start", so the Jeffreys' prior is IMO the most reasonable choice.

Comment: Added the proof for the likelihood.  For the proof of the prior, you'll have to read Jeffreys' paper.

Comment: @user777: I think that for any particular distribution $d$ of a continuous exponential family, there is a sample space transformation that makes it so that $d$ is uniform over the new sample space.  In other words, this intuition about something being uniform, multimodal or unimodal is probably irrelevant.  Specifically, $\textrm{Beta}(\frac12, \frac12)$ is unimodal if you were to transform the sample space to be the space of log-odds.